# What I should write in my models.py to connect two ManyToMany forms?

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

I want to add auto-service, it has list of brands of cars and services in M2M field.
For each brand of car I should link several services.

Please help me to write code I'm a beginner trying to make website.

here is url to picture, take a look

https://ibb.co/31DZZJ1

Answer (score 0):

Well,I don't want to write everything. But Basically, you will have two models.

```
class CarBrand(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
services = models.ManyToManyField('Services', blank=True)
```

```
class Services(models.Model):
service_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then you can add these models to your admin and once you fill the services model admin will show you a list of services and you can select the ones you want for each car brand in the car brand model..

Sorry I am not good at explaining. but ask me if you don't understand